# Bash Newbie's question: How to launch CMake GUI after successfully installed CMake GUI

Tags: bash, macos, cmake

I need to use CMake on macOS to generate xcode project. Since I'm not very experienced with bash so I follow other developers' suggestion to install CMake GUI:

```
1) - Install macPorts
2) - Install CMake GUI by "sudo port install cmake +gui"
```

All installations are successfully completed and cmake GUI is properly built, but i do not know how to launch cmake with GUI. Use "cmake" still launch the cmake command line edition. Thanks for any suggestions.

**Update:**
I use bash command "`type cmake-gui`" to get the location of the cmake GUI directory and it is "`/opt/local/bin/cmake-gui`". However, I can not "CD" into this directory and bash saids that "Not a directory"? So where is the built app of cmake GUI?

Comment: `cmake-gui` should not be a folder. It's an executable. Or did you mean you can't cd to `/opt/local/bin/`

Comment: try `ls -l /opt/local/bin/cmake-gui`

Comment: Event it is not symbolic link? I saw the CMake GUI building script succeeded, so do you have idea where is the final built .app is put?

Comment: The is the ls result "-rwxr-xr-x", not a directory, so where is the cmake gui app built?

Comment: Does that matter? The temporary location was probably deleted.

Comment: Forgive me for basic knowledge on Unix bash. All I need to know is how to launch Cmake with GUI after I built it, do you have suggestions?

Comment: `/opt/local/bin/cmake-gui` is probably all you need.

Comment: Thanks, it is working. If you put your last suggestion as answer, I'll accept it as the final answer. By the way, on macOS, is there a way to add this cmake-gui to system path so that I can launch it any where?

Comment: You probably need to put `/opt/local/bin/` in your path. I don't know how to to that on macOS.